# ReferenceError: window is not defined in react laravel project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, npm

I have installed react inside laravel project using

```
composer require laravel/ui 
php artisan ui react
```

I can run laravel server with `php artisan serve` fine. Now I also want to run `npm start`. Here is my `package.json` file.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node resources/js/app.js", 
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2"
    }
}
```

When I run `npm start` I find this error message:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

How to solve this ? Thanks.

**Edit:**
Usually I am used to create react project with the `npx create-react-app my-app` command. Then I run `npm start` to run the server at `localhost:3000`. But this time I installed react inside laravel with the help of `laravel/ui`. Now I want to start react server with `npm start` command as I am used to.

Comment: You are setting the window variable to lodash, read the error backwards, it seems your problem is coming from lodash. Check if lodash is installed or properly imported.


I bet whatever you change that window variable to, will also not be defined, because the variable is referencing something that is not defined!

Comment: @saas_joel I did not install lodash manually. It installed with the react or laravel installation. How do I check if it's installed properly or imported ?

Comment: try this 


var _ = require('lodash');

rather than using window

Comment: @saas_joel where do I add var _ = require('lodash');  ?

Comment: Where did you get your `start` script from??

Comment: @saas_joel The issue has nothing to do with `lodash`. Also, In the example `_` is being set to `lodash` not the `window` object itself. :)

Comment: @saas_joel, I got it. But it did not solve the issue and shows new error message. Although npm run watch compiles fine. 
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this issue is because `node` doesn't have the `window` variable and your `start` script is literally just trying to run the `resources/js/app.js` file with `node`.

I'm not sure what your goal was with your `start` script but I would suggest using either the `dev`, `watch` or `prod` commands that came with the install instead. This way your code should actually get compiled and be usable in the browser.

Comment: I did not add any extra start script here is my app.js and bootstrap.js file
https://pastebin.com/ucF1ZFxM

Comment: @KamrulHasan Ah fair enough, I thought you might have since I've just installed a fresh version and I couldn't see ` "start": "node resources/js/app.js", ` in the `package.json`. In that case, I would suggest removing the `start` script and just using one of the other commands e.g. `npm run dev`.

Comment: Still I am able perform npm run dev. But what I want to achieve is to run node server with npm start command.

Comment: @KamrulHasan Oh right, so you did add `"start": "node resources/js/app.js",` (the start script)? Please could you update your question with a little description about what you want/need the node server for as it's not quite clear.

Comment: I have updated my question. Have a look.